# How to Create Custom Module in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento2.3, magento1.9.3

I am using magento version 1.9

I want to create module for FAQ's Questions and Answers.

In this module I want to create one form on front-end for inserting FAQ and in back-end admin panel. I want custom grid using which admin can view,edit delete,update,search FAQ as well as admin can also send response to the client's FAQ.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use this module for Magento 1 https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-faq

Comment: Thank you so much -Pradip Garchar

Comment: Welcome anytime :)